# Ember Model: Using Custom Primary Key makes attribute lose value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my **Customer** model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    customerId: DS.attr('string'),
    customerName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This is my **Customer Serializer**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey : 'customerId' // I am defining customerId as primary key
});
```

This is my **JSON Response** from server

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "customerId": "1",
      "customerName": "name 1"
    },
    {
      "customerId": "2",
      "customerName": "name 2"
    },
    {
      "customerId": "3",
      "customerName": "name 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything works fine, But then when i try to get customerId, i get undefined.

sample code

```
var x = getModelInstanceFromWhere();
x.get('id'); //=> returns : "1"
x.get('customerId'); //=> returns :  undefined
x.get('customerName'); //=> returns :  "name 1"
x.toJSON(); //=> return obj: {customerId:undefined,customerName:"name 1"}
x.get('data'); //=> return obj: {id:"1",customerName:"name 1"}
```

I want to get customerId value, even when using customerId as primary key.
Something like x.get('customerId') must give me customerId rather than undefined

Comment: In your serializer can't you normalize your JSON into a format ember is happier with, so you would normalize `customerId` to `id` as ember-data expects?

Comment: Essentially the `primaryKey` property works as a mechanism for informing the serializer to move that property to and from the named `primaryKey`.

Comment: If you really want the functionality you are looking for, build up a custom serializer and override this function: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.13.4/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json-serializer.js#L727

Comment: @Kingpin2k Can you pls post it as answer, so that i can mark it as solved.